# A JIRA issue: Cross-teams cards take unexpected sprint value to my report

Tags: jira

I have a sprint board on JIRA, the cards come from kinds of other project, but it take sprint from other project as well when I use report function on JIRA.

Please see below screen shot as an example: The sprint value in red area come from other project.
I don't want to see them and I don't know how to resolve it.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I post the question to community.atlassian.com and get useful reply.: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Jira-Software-questions/A-JIRA-issue-Cross-teams-cards-take-unexpected-sprint-value-to/qaq-p/2094299?utm_campaign=mentions_answer&utm_content=post&utm_medium=email&utm_source=atlcomm#M209804